# Calculated date to be a working day

Tags: calculated-column, date

I have a column that I call 'Agenda Due Date'. I have been using the following formula to calculate the agenda due date which is 1 working day before the 'review meeting date' which I have as a separate column that is entered manually.  If the 'Review Date' is blank then I want the 'Agenda Due Date' to be blank.

My problem is if the Review date is on a Monday, the Agenda Due Date is the Sunday.  I want the due date be the Friday before.  How do I change the formula to only consider working days?

```
=IF([Review Date]="","",[Review Date]-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula:

> =IF([Review Date]="","", IF(TEXT(WEEKDAY([Review Date]), "dddd") = "Monday", [Review Date]-3, [Review Date] - 1))

Comment: For docs and examples on usable Formulas see: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that did not work

Comment: Did you get exception? It is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, it looks like you need to create an event receiver which triggered when you create / submit a new item (There is a great reference [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5b1f04/create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-for-item-added-in/) on how to add an event receiver to a List/Library). For example, when a new item is added to the list (Not Tested):

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    SPList item = properties.ListItem;
    DateTime reviewDate = DateTime.parse(item["Review_x0020_Date"].ToString());
    item["Agenda_x0020_Due_x0020_Date"] = GetPreviousWorkingDay(reviewDate);
    item.Update();
}

    private static DateTime GetPreviousWorkingDay(DateTime reviewDate)
    {
        reviewDate = reviewDate.AddDays(-1);
        while (!IsWorkingDay(reviewDate))
        {
            reviewDate = reviewDate.AddDays(-1);
        }

        return reviewDate;
    }

private bool IsWorkingDay(DateTime date)
{
    if(date.DayOfWeek== DayOfWeek.Sunday || date.DayOfWeek== DayOfWeek.Saturday)
         return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: -1 , This is an *If you have a hammer, everything starts to look like a nail* answer. SharePoint Calculated Column Formulas are a subset of Excel formulas, so can do a lot.

Comment: Ah.. I see.. Sorry to not having a proper research first about the Calculated Column Formulas..

Comment: A little difficult for me and am using SharePoint 2010 with very basic knowledge of SharePoint Designer.  Thanks anyways.